# How to best stop problems when the VPN fails

Tags: networking, vpn

I have a VPN that is frequently on for hours or days.  It is set to block traffic on the net when the connection goes down, but periodically the application itself fails -- meaning that not only does it not work, it also doesn't block traffic.

One question is whether this matters much if I'm not actively using the browser.  For example, if a page is up and loaded and then the VPN fails, will the URLs be visible to the ISP immediately?  Or is it only on subsequent page clicks or RESTful services, etc.?

Comment: I have removed the software request portion of your question as we do not recommend software products explicitly. You may wish to further edit your question to clarify it, or add a portion about detecting and resolving situations when the VPN fails.

Comment: @music2myear Sure, sorry.  I'm not sure I even know the search words to get to that in Google, so perhaps someone can tell me what those are called if they indeed exist?  Some kind of VPN monitor?

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you, sounds like it just depends on the actual page that I've loaded.  Would there be a way to tell if a page is actively refreshing its content and/or block that with a browser plugin or some such tool?